# How to insert div at the end of a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following code:

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="new-item">hello!</div>
```

Which looks like this in my testing:

[image]

Notice how the `hello` is on the next row.

Is there any way to instead have it inserted after the grid above? Such that it is the last grid item? Such that it is in line with it, instead of being on the next row.

The obvious solution is to just place the `new-item` div as a child of `my-grid`, but I cannot do that in my case, because `my-grid` is an external component from the internet, so I cannot insert something inside of it.

These two elements also have a common parent as well. Which can be anything.

Comment: do they have a common container/parent element?

Comment: add it to the question so I can add an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `display: contents` if they share the same container:

```css
/* transfer all the styles to container 
   in the near future you can do .container:has(.my-grid) {}
*/
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 300px;
}

/* we remove "my-grid" div*/
.my-grid {
  display: contents; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="new-item">hello!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work in my case because it modifies the class of the `my-grid` element, which is an external component. I'll have to see if I can style it. Is there any way to do it without modifying `my-grid` or their children?

Comment: In addition, this is a bit concerning, no? https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Comment: @RyanPeschel you don't have to worry about the support. All the browsers support it but it may have a few issues with special element like button but not with divs. And if you cannot change the CSS of my-grid then it's not possible with my idea.

Comment: Ah good point! Oh, darn. Hmm, well I'll look into seeing if I can change the CSS. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: @RyanPeschel as long as you don't have buttons or tables in your grid, it should be fine on the latest versions of most browsers. This is what I would probably do as well . An alternative would be to reorganise the HTML using JS - which is ugly, but can work

Answer (score 0):

You can set absolute position on "new-item" and if you have a div container above "my-grid" do not forget to set "position: relative", on it. Then you can adjust the left and top of "new-item", relative to the main div container. Might course some problem in different  resolutions of the screen,  adress it with some media queries.